# Richtige Verwendung von "offenbar"

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Nach meinem Sprachgefühl ist ein Sachverhalt "offenbar", wenn er in irgendeinem Sinn offensichtlich erkennbar ist. In deutschen Zeitungen findet sich aber "offenbar" oft im Sinne von "scheinbar", "anscheinend" oder "wahrscheinlich". [Beispiel der FAZ](http://www.faz.net/aktuell/wirtschaft/europas-schuldenkrise/transferunion-regierung-schliesst-eurobonds-offenbar-nicht-mehr-aus-11112648.html):

> Regierung schließt Eurobonds offenbar nicht mehr aus

Speziell in der FAZ finden sich [viele weitere Beispiele](https://www.google.com/search?as_q=offenbar&as_sitesearch=faz.net) dieser Verwendung von "offenbar", die auf mich teilweise einen witzig-grotesken Eindruck machen ("Offenbar Steuern hinterzogen").

Meine Frage: Ist diese Verwendung korrekt und mein Sprachgefühl falsch?

Comment: *scheinbar* ist übrigens nicht dasselbe wie *anscheinend*. Zum Beispiel: *die scheinbar unlösbare Aufgabe* (sie *ist* lösbar, sie scheint/schien nur unlösbar zu sein)

Comment: Das ist mir auch aufgefallen.  Es klingt so bestimmt, bedeutet aber wohl in Wirklichkeit "es gibt jemanden, der das behauptet, wir können das aber nicht nachprüfen".

Comment: Zeitungen sind für gute Rechtschreibung schon seit langem kein gutes Beispiel mehr. Noch zur Abgrenzung zwischen scheinbar und anscheinend: Scheinbar: Es scheint nur so zu sein, aber es ist klar, dass der Schein trügt. Anscheinend - es scheint nicht nur so zu sein sondern könnte (oder ist tatsächlich) so.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dein Sprachgefühl täuschte Dich nicht, wenn ["offenbar" als Adjektiv](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/offenbar_bekannt_klar_offenkundig) verwendet worden wäre:

> offen zutage tretend, klar ersichtlich

Allerdings wird hier ["offenbar" als Adverb](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/offenbar_unzweifelhaft_augenfaellig) benutzt, was die Bedeutung ein wenig verschiebt:

> dem Anschein nach, wie es scheint

Aber auch:

> offenkundig, offensichtlich

Dein Sprachgefühl kennt nur die zusätzliche Geschmacksrichtung (noch) nicht.

Comment: +1 so ist es auch im [DWDS](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=offenbar&view=1) zu lesen.

Comment: Mal sehen, ob sich mein Sprachgefühl noch daran gewöhnt. Schließlich bedeutet "offenbaren" ja auch "offenbar werden lassen". Interessant fände ich noch, seit wann "offenbar" als Adverb diese von "offen" weiter entferntere Bedeutung bekommen hat.

Comment: Oh, der Link von @Takkat scheint diese Frage zu beantworten: "ahd. _offenbāri_ ‘feierlich, augenscheinlich’ (10. Jh.)" Mein Sprachgefühl kann sich also nicht mit "neumodischer Quatsch!" herausreden.

Answer (score 5):

*Offenbar* als Ersatz für *scheinbar* halte ich für falsch, als Synonym zu *anscheinend* hingegen nicht (vgl. auch [Unterschied zwischen *scheinbar* und *anscheinend*](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/3126/what-is-the-difference-between-scheinbar-and-anscheinend)). Ich glaube, in der Quelle ist auch *anscheinend* gemeint.

Der Duden listet unter den [Synonymen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/anscheinend) von *anscheinend* auch *offenbar* (umgekehrt zwar nicht, aber immerhin steht bei beiden in der Bedeutung "dem Anschein nach").

Da sich die FAZ im konkreten Fall der Eurobonds auf einen Zeitungsartikel beruft, lässt sich *offenbar* auch durch *anscheinend* oder ein ähnliches Synonym ersetzen. Insofern sehe ich keinen Grund zur Beanstandung bei der genannten Verwendung.